# Pytest playwright test works in debug mode but fails during normal run

Tags: chromium, playwright, playwright-python

I am trying to create a test script using Pytest and Playwright. My test works well in webkit. But has problems in Chromium. The test even works well in the debug mode (PWDEBUG=1). However on initiating a normal run with Chromium, the app under test seems to behave differently. A Javascript controlled file upload does not work. I have put in the problematic parts of my script below but I am thinking that this is something more fundamental. Eg. I need to allow certain types of popups in Chromium during browser context creation or something along those lines. This is more so because my test works with the Webkit driver and also in Chromium with debug mode on.

EDIT: When I framed the original question I forgot to mention that the reason for the failure is that element is not found by playwright and the script times out.

Test script lines

```
page2.locator("#uploadDocument").set_input_files("pytest_tests\\TestDownloads\\online_application_"+app_timestamp+".pdf")
```

Page element

```
<div class="input-container">
<label for="uploadDocument">Upload signed documents <a class="i-tooltip" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" href="#pd" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Format must be in PDF">
<i class="icon-question-sign"></i>
</a>
</label>
<div class="custom-file"><input type="file" class="hidden-file-input" id="uploadDocument" name="uploadDocument" accept="application/pdf">
<label class="custom-file-label" for="uploadDocument"><span class="custom-file-input" id="ChooseFile" name="ChooseFile" style="color: gray;">
</span><i class="icon-upload-alt"></i>
</label>
</div>
</div>
```

NOTE: I have tried using filechooser and it has the same results (works on webkit not on chromium)

Comment: Please share the error with stacktrace.

Comment: It might be a little late to give a stacktrace since I am not assigned to this anymore, but the issue is that the element is not recognized (only on this specific browser) and it times out. Needless to say that the stacktrace only shows a time out and nothing else. FWIW I have modified the question to reflect this.